# column match and get sum from different column

Tags: r

Hello I am very new to R, and I am trying to solve probably very simple question.
so, here it is:

```
c1   c2   c3   c4
a    8    f    5
b    9    c    4
c    7    b    3 
d    5    a    2
e    1    d    5
f    5    e    4
```

I want to match column c1 and c3 and get total of c2 and c4
so answer should look like

```
a   10
b   12
c   11
...
```

I have used match function to obtain match between 2 columns, and i got that, but i am not sure how to get total from other columns

Please help me, this is just an example, but if works, i can solve my sequencing data.

thank you.

Comment: Are these columns in one data.frame or separate data.frames?

Answer (score 2):

You can try something like:

```
## Your data.frame
df <- data.frame(c1=letters[1:6], c2=c(8,9,7,5,1,5), 
                 c3=c("f", "c", "b", "a", "d", "e"), c4=c(5,4,3,2,5,4))

## Match the indices of column 1 to column 3
m <- match(df$c1, df$c3)

## Sum columns 2 and 4, where 4 is rearanged to match column 1
data.frame(c1 = df$c1, ans = df$c2 + df$c4[m])

##  c1 ans
##  1  a  10
##  2  b  12
##  3  c  11
##  4  d  10
##  5  e   5
##  6  f  10
```

Hope it helps,

alex

Answer (score 1):

This might not be the most efficient way but it should work:

```
# Split the data into two frames
temp1 = data.frame(a=data$a, b=data$b)
temp2 = data.frame(c=data$c, d=data$d)

#Now merge them based on the 'a' and 'c' columns
out = merge(temp1,temp2, by.x='a', by.y='c')

#Now we can sum the 'b' and 'd' columns
out$sum = out$b+out$d
```

That should give you what you want?

Answer (score 1):

This could also work

```
#sample data
dd<-data.frame(
    c1 = c("a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f"), 
    c2 = c(8L, 9L, 7L, 5L, 1L, 5L), 
    c3 = c("f", "c", "b", "a", "d", "e"), 
    c4 = c(5L, 4L, 3L, 2L, 5L, 4L)
)

#stopifnot(levels(dd$c1)=levels(dd$c3))

sums <- with(dd, c2[order(c1)]+c4[order(c3)])
```

Basically you just resort `c2` and `c4` so they are in order corresponding to the paired factor then add straight across.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a suggestion, though it will only work if the elements of c1 and c3 are all unique. If that is the case, you could use the `which()` function. Something like this: `c2[which(c1 == x)] + c4[which(c3) == x]` would give you the sum of the value of c2 when c1 is x and the value of c4 when c3 is x.